# Google Cloud Messaging , how to control the message queue?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have implemented Google Cloud Messaging on Android. When the device is no internet connection and receives messages accumulate in queue and when he returns to have internet connection receives all. This is a problem for me. I want that when the device has more than one message queue receives only one. This is possible?

Is there any way to see the queue on the server?

Thank you

**Update...**

Work fine...

```
$fields = array(
            'registration_ids' => $registrationIDs,
            'data' => array("message" => $message),
            'collapse_key' => $collapse_key,
        );
```

Comment: A few months ago the answer was 'no'. I haven't heard of any changes to GCM so unlikely but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do that with `collapse_key`.

It all the messages have the same `collapge_key`, only the last message will be stored in GCM server and delivered to the device when it's back online.

> **collapse_key**
>
> An arbitrary string (such as "Updates Available") that is used to collapse a group of like messages when the device is offline, so that only the last message gets sent to the client. This is intended to avoid sending too many messages to the phone when it comes back online. Note that since there is no guarantee of the order in which messages get sent, the "last" message may not actually be the last message sent by the application server. Collapse keys are also called send-to-sync messages.

([Source](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html))

Comment: @kbi You're welcome! Don't worry about the upvote. You can still accept the answer :)